# Unable To Load Dynamic Library in VSCode Terminal - PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have a web server setup with XAMPP, the website works completely fine, no errors or issues with loading extensions.

I have Visual Studio Code setup to remote reference the php.exe by referencing by \ipAddr\php\php.exe within the settings of VSCode. This enables me to execute scripts within the Terminal. But, I am getting the following warning for each extension that is loaded -

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll' - The specified module could not be
>   found.

It seems that vscode/php.exe terminal is trying to find the **C:\xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll** within the client PC.

Has anyone got a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the file php_bz2.dll exist at C:\xampp\php\ext\ ?
If not, probably you should search for it at web, or try to re-install xampp or get the newest version one.